# Understanding behaviour of self with static variables

Tags: python, static-variables

I am confused with the behaviour of self when it comes to dealing with static variables in python.From what I understand is that static variables can be accessed by either using `classname.variablename` or `self.variablename`. However changing the value of that variable differs. I realized that if i change the static variable value by `classname.variablename=SomeValue` the instance variable reflects that value however if I change the value of static variable using `self.variablename=SomeValue` the static variable does not change when access like `classname.variablename` from what I understand is that when I assign a value like `self.variablename=SomeValue` then an instance variable is created. Can somebody please shed a little light on this behaviour.

Example 1:

```
class bean:
    mycar="SomeCar"
    def test(self):
        bean.mycar = "yup"
        print(self.mycar) #prints yup
```

Example 2:

```
class bean:
        mycar="SomeCar"
        def test(self):
            self.mycar = "pup"
            print(bean.mycar) #SomeCar
```

Comment: No no no no. [Read this](https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide) or something similar: class attributes vs instance attributes.

Comment: You are setting it on the instance with `self.variablename = SomeValue`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak great link

Comment: Short answer: essentially you are shadowing the class variable with an instance variable of the same name in your second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both classes and instances can have attributes.

A class attribute is assigned to a class object. People sometimes call this a *"static variable"*.

An instance attribute is assigned to an instance (*"instance variable"*).

When an attribute of an object is **read**, a number of things happen (see [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)), but the short version is:

1. Try to read the attribute from the instance
2. If that fails, try to read it from the class

When it is **written**, then there is no such mechanism. It is written where it is written ;)

See in example:

```
class A(object):
    pass

a = A()

print A.value  # fails - there is no "value" attribute
print a.value  # fails - there is no "value" attribute

A.value = 7

print A.value  # prints 7
print a.value  # also prints 7 - there is no attribute on instance, but there is on class

a.value = 11

print A.value  # prints 7
print a.value  # prints 11 - now there is an attribute on the instance

a2 = A()

print a2.value  # prints 7 - this instance has no "value", but the class has
```

**self?**

BTW, the `self` argument (in the question) is an instance, just like `a` is here.

Answer (score 1):

`self` in python is an ordinary name that binds the reference to the *instance* calling a class method. It is passed as the first argument to a method and by convention, it is bound to the name 'self'. When `self.variable = value` is called, you are setting the value of an instance variable; a variable unique to that *particular* `bean`.

For example, `self.name = "Fred"` might name my mother's bean, but I named my own bean "George" when I called `self.name` from *my* bean.

On the other hand, `bean.name = "Yousef"` names *all* beans. My mother's bean is now named "Yousef", and so is mine.

If my Dad has a bean as well, he'll be surprised to find out that it too, is named "Yousef" when he calls `bean.name`. But he can still use `self.name` to give his bean its own (possibly unique) name.

### Example Code:

```
class bean:
    name = "Yousef"  # All beans have this name with `bean.name`

moms = bean()
mine = bean()
dads = bean()

beans = [moms, mine, dads]

# Primitive tabular output function
def output(bean_list):
    print("-bean-", "\t", "-self-")
    for b in bean_list:
        print(bean.name, "\t", b.name)
    print("") # Separate output sets with a newline

# Print the names with only the class attribute set
output(beans)

# Python magic using zip to apply names simultaneously
# Mom's bean is "Fred", mine is "George"
# My dad is weird and named his "Ziggaloo"
for b, n in zip(beans, ["Fred", "George", "Ziggaloo"]):
    b.name = n

# Print the names after applying `self.name`
output(beans)
```

### Python 3.4 Output:

```
-bean-   -self-
Yousef   Yousef
Yousef   Yousef
Yousef   Yousef

-bean-   -self-
Yousef   Fred
Yousef   George
Yousef   Ziggaloo
```

Comment: "`self` in python is a special keyword" - no, it's just an argument name like any other. Any other variable holding a `bean` instance would exhibit the same behavior on attribute access and assignment.

Comment: @user2357112 Fair enough. I've edited to correct this, and hopefully it better expresses that `self` is special in the sense that it is automatically provided, but not special in the sense that it operates like an ordinary variable identifier in python.

Comment: Aaron3468, I still find your phrasing misleading (hence my downvote). I suggest that you make it clear that "self" is in no way special, what matters is the *first argument to bound methods*. You could call it `this` or `potato` if you liked. You probably know this, but your post can be misleading in my opinion. (cc @user2357112)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I've corrected this, and if you find it still misleading, feel free to suggest an edit